# Android: Package name, Do i really need a domain name?

Tags: android, eclipse, dns

This will probably be closed.
But my question is do I really need to own a domain name to release my app?
also if i happen to use some one elses with out knowing it com.jellyfish.taxicap can i get in trouble for it. Also is it possible to just make a package name up like abc.jellyfish.taxicap.

thank you
sorry for the format

Comment: Most likely, for marketing reasons more so than anything else. Many developers think that all you have to do is upload the app to the Play Store and the world will find your app. These developers are mistaken. Marketing apps in this day and age usually involves a Web site, which usually involves a domain name. Using that domain name as part of your Android app package name is merely a useful side benefit.

Comment: You won't get into trouble for using someone else's domain name but I'd recommend you get one of your own if for no other reason that it helps organise your apps and package files and you won't have to remember what "made up" name you used last time. Registering a domain is fairly easy (if you have a credit card) and doesn't cost much. I have two domains which cost around a total of 10 USD per year to maintain. As long as I keep paying each year I'll own the domains for life.

Comment: All of theses answer really help thank you, if I publish some apps with out a domain name can i always go back later on and change it to the domain name?

Comment: "can i always go back later on and change it to the domain name?" -- you cannot readily change a published app's package name.

Comment: I bet you'll be in storm of trouble like that Mike Roe guy when he made the MikeRoeSoft domain.  Just don't DBA doing business as some domain name.  Make something unique that you can live with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  That's not a domain name.  It's just used as a unique identifier by the app.  It has nothing to do with a domain, even though it sorta looks like one.

It does, however, need to be unique.  And you shpould try to choose something personal, and easily identified.